# Button can't apply Template Syntax in Vue

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, components, vue-component

im very confused about the code in my Vue Component since any Element apply the template from `{{ title }}` except one **button** that only shows the template syntax as plain HTML.

[Generated Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVIYN.png)

My Code:

```
<template>
  <li>
    <h2>{{ friend.name }}</h2>
    <!-- this button has the {{ title }} in it, but vue wont render it when generating the page -->
    <button>{‌{ title }}</button>
    <!-- this p-tag on the other hand got the same syntax template and works just fint -->
    <p>{{ title }}</p>
    <ul v-if="detailsAreVisible">
      <li><strong>Phone: </strong>{{ friend.phone }}</li>
      <li><strong>Email: </strong>{{ friend.email }}</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</template>
    
    <script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      //this the string that should be inside the button
      title: "HELLO",
      detailsAreVisible: false,
      friend: {
        id: "max",
        name: "Max Musterman",
        phone: "0151 2548 425",
        email: "max@localhost.de",
      },
    };
  },
  methods: {
    toggleDetails() {
      this.detailsAreVisible = !this.detailsAreVisible;
    },
  },
  computed: {
    toggleButtonText() {
      let innerText = this.detailsAreVisible ? "Hide" : "Show";
      return innerText + " Details";
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you copy past the {{ title }} one `dot` also past between brackets thats why it's not showing.
[image]

```js
        const app = new Vue({
        data() {
    return {
      //this the string that should be inside the button
      title: "HELLO",
      detailsAreVisible: false,
      friend: {
        id: "max",
        name: "Max Musterman",
        phone: "0151 2548 425",
        email: "max@localhost.de",
      },
    };
  },
        })
        app.$mount("#app")
```

```html
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
      
  <div id="app">
  <li>
    <h2>{{ friend.name }}</h2>
    <!-- this button has the {{ title }} in it, but vue wont render it when generating the page -->
    <button>{{ title }}</button>
    <!-- this p-tag on the other hand got the same syntax template and works just fint -->
    <p>{{ title }}</p>
    <ul v-if="detailsAreVisible">
      <li><strong>Phone: </strong>{{ friend.phone }}</li>
      <li><strong>Email: </strong>{{ friend.email }}</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you have some char between the first `{{` in the button. if you check how many chars is in the first `{{` you see 3 chars not 2.
you can see in the image here that you had some char between (i just copy it and that what i see)

[image: bad char]

just delete it and type it again :-). this is probably due to some copy paste or something like this

or you can copy it from here and paste it in you code and it should works
`{{ title }}`